# Significant Delay in Receiving Data using Python Select()

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, delay

I have a Python script that is used to receive data associated with a radio station audio event (such as a song or commercial) from the machine playing the audio. The script will parse and process the data and then send portions of it to various other destinations.

First the socket is set up:

```
client_socket_1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    print 'trying to open socket 1'
    client_socket_1.connect((TCP_RCV_IP_CR1, TCP_RCV_PORT_CR1))
    client_socket_1.setblocking(0)
except socket.error, e:
    print 'Error', e, TCP_RCV_IP_CR1, '\n\n\n'
else:
    SOCK1 = 1
    print 'Successful connection to ',TCP_RCV_IP_CR1,'\n'
```

Now we wait until data is available to be read. I used select() and when the socket is ready to be read, the thread that parses and processes the data is spawned.

```
ready_1 = select.select([client_socket_1], [], [], 1)   # select tells us when data is available at the socket
if ready_1[0] and SOCK1:        # Don't run this code if there is no connection on client_socket_1 or no data available
    t1 = Thread(target=processdata1)    # Set up the thread
    t1.start()  # Call the process to process available data as a thread
```

It is important that the data be read as quickly as possible as it will be transported via TCP or UDP (depending on the particular data chunks and program specifications) along with the associated audio, and the function of one of the data items we are handling can create an on-air 'hiccup' in the audio if not received in a timely fashion. (TMI: It causes a 'replacement' commercial to play at the receiving end which is supposed to 'cover' the commercial audio we are sending. If the replacement spot doesn't start quickly enough listeners will hear the beginning of the commercial we are sending, then the local replacement one will start when our data is received and it sounds like a hiccup on the air.)

To confirm that my script is not always receiving the data quickly enough I telnetted to the port it is listening to and watched the data as it is received in the telnet window, then look at the Python output (which sends received data to stdout as soon as it is received) and I see about a 1.5-second delay between the telnet output and the Python output. This is the same amount of delay we have observed in normal on-air operation.

I chose to use select() because I was asked to multi-thread the script and I thought that would be a good way to know when to trigger a data-processing thread. My original idea was to simply loop through attempting to read data from each of the three systems we are monitoring and, when data is found, process it.

The thought was that if data is being processed from one system when another system has data ready to be read, it might cause a delay in processing and sending out the data from that machine. However, I can't see that delay being as significant as what I am experiencing now. I am considering going back to the original plan.

I would rather stick with what I have which is working flawlessly as long as data is received in a timely fashion. Any thoughts on why the excessively long delay?

Comment: You have an interesting problem here. After searching around, I can't find a single post anywhere related to `select` being slow (in Python or at the OS level). Therefore, I think your problem actually lies elsewhere. I recommend you try debugging a bit more or write a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can try helping out a bit.

Comment: On which platform are you running the code? The docs say: ``Empty sequences are allowed, but acceptance of three empty sequences is platform-dependent. (It is known to work on Unix but not on Windows.)``

Comment: Running on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with your `timeout` parameter in combination with the `wlist` and `xlist` parameters
Consider this piece of code

```
write_list = []
exception_list = []
select.select([client_socket_1], write_list, exception_list)
```

It takes an optional timeout parameter, like you use it. The documentation says

> select() also takes an optional fourth parameter which is the number
>   of seconds to wait before breaking off monitoring if no channels have
>   become active. Using a timeout value lets a main program call select()
>   as part of a larger processing loop, taking other actions in between
>   checking for network input.

It might be that the call will always wait one second before returning because of the empty lists. Try

```
ready_1 = select.select(
    [client_socket_1], 
    [client_socket_1], 
    [client_socket_1], 1
)
```

Or you can use a timeout value of 0, which

> specifies a poll and never blocks.

Comment: Thanks...going to try this first. Will report back.

Comment: Wasn't able to test this solution out until this morning due to a sick daughter yesterday. This does not seem to be the problem. I can't really measure the exact amount of delay but it seems at times that it may be somewhat less, however it is still significant enough to be a problem. I did try both populating the other two lists with client_socket_1 and a timeout of 0.